# What needs to be assigned to a lookup field when using createRecord in salesforce lwc js?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I tried passing opportunity id and name

```
        quotefields[OPPORTUNITY_FIELD.fieldApiName] = ???;
        const recordInput1 = { apiName: QUOTE_OBJECT.objectApiName, quotefields };
        console.log(recordInput1)

        //creating a quote
        createRecord(recordInput1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no such specific requirements to a lookup field.
you just have to pass the id of the record as a string that you want to lookup from the created record.